# Using char pointer vs char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to write a simple program, which reads a word and prints the number of times, that the letter "e" was used. When i implement my programm with a char array it works.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #define N 10

int main() {

int i, count=0;
char c[N];

scanf("%s", c);

for (i=0;i<N;i++){
    if( c[i] == 'e') count++;
   }
printf("%d", count);
}
```

But using a char pointer, my programm crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10

int main() {

int i, count=0;
char *c;
scanf("%s", c);

while(*c != '/0'){
    if( *c == 'e') count++;
    c = c +1;
}
printf("%d", count);
}
```

Is it just not possible to implement it like this?

Comment: No, it's not. /15char

Comment: You need to allocate memory to store it in the pointer. read about `malloc()`.

Comment: `\0` vs `/0` - the direction of that slash kind of matters!

Comment: No, your first version does not work either. Try typing in "aeeeeeeeeeeeeee" (overruns buffer) or "ee" (arbitrary resuts)

Comment: Who said that pointer == array? It is not, despite many thinking it is.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid input buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior, when calling `scanf()` with the `%s` format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  I.E.  this:

```
scanf("%s", c);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%9s", c);
```

Also, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current scenario:

```
if( 1 != scanf( "%9s", c) ) 
{
    perror( "scanf for string failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, scanf successful
```

The problem with the second version of the code (beyond the above) is that the declaration:

```
char *c;
```

only defines the pointer, NOT where it points

suggest adding the code block:

```
if( NULL == (c = malloc( N ) ) )
{
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful
```

Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in `stdlib.h`

Note: `perror()` is found in `stdio.h`

Of course, since the code performed a `malloc()` Then at any later point in the code where it is exiting, it should also pass the pointer to `free()`